# Is there a design pattern for light & heavy versions of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have the need for both light-weight, and heavy-weight versions of an object in my application.

- A light-weight object would contain only ID fields, but no instances of related classes.
- A heavy-weight object would contain IDs, and instances of those classes.

Here is an example class (for purpose of discussion only):

```
public class OrderItem
{
    // FK to Order table
    public int OrderID;
    public Order Order;

    // FK to Prodcut table
    public int ProductID;
    public Product Product;

    // columns in OrderItem table
    public int Quantity;
    public decimal UnitCost;

    // Loads an instance of the object without linking to objects it relates to.
    // Order, Product will be NULL.
    public static OrderItem LoadOrderItemLite()
    {
        var reader = // get from DB Query
        var item = new OrderItem();
        item.OrderID = reader.GetInt("OrderID");
        item.ProductID = reader.GetInt("ProductID");
        item.Quantity = reader.GetInt("Quantity");
        item.UnitCost = reader.GetDecimal("UnitCost");
        return item;
    }

    // Loads an instance of the objecting and links to all other objects.
    // Order, Product objects will exist.
    public static OrderItem LoadOrderItemFULL()
    {
        var item = LoadOrderItemLite();
        item.Order = Order.LoadFULL(item.OrderID);
        item.Product = Product.LoadFULL(item.ProductID);
        return item;
    }
}
```

**Is there a good design pattern to follow to accomplish this?**

I can see how it can be coded into a single class (as my example above), but it is not apparent in which way an instance is being used.  I would need to have NULL checks throughout my code.

**Edit:**
This object model is being used on client side of client-server application.  In the case where I'm using the light-weight objects, I don't want lazy load because it will be a waste of time and memory ( I will already have the objects in memory on client side elsewhere)

Answer (score 3):

Lazy initialization, Virtual Proxy and Ghost are three implementations of that lazy loading pattern. Basically they refer to load properties once you need them. Now, I suppose you'll be using some repo to store objects so I'll encourage you to use any of the ORM tools available. (Hibernate, Entity Framework and so on), they all implement these functionality free for you.

Comment: I don't always want to load the full object.  And sometimes, I already have an instance of it, so I don't need to re-load from DB anyways.

Comment: @TheSean It doesn't matter. That's precisely the utility of the pattern. If you need to use them, then you load them, otherwise not. Now, If you're talking about to not expose heavy-version properties that's other thing, but also can be solved by using (i.e. two interfaces: the lighter one and the heavy one).

Comment: As an example, say I have 1,000 orders, each for the same product.  With your suggestion to lazy load the Product object, I would load 1,000 instances of the same object.  This is what I mean by waste of memory.

Comment: @TheSean I'm pretty sure all of the named ORM manage that scenario (pretty common for high orders of magnitude), now, if you one to manage it by hand you also can, implement the lazy loading -again :)- but now have, say, a cache, where you manage previously instanced entities from your repo, and given that they are reference types, there must not be any kind of overload. (Obviously entity modification will present another problem but.. you can get the idea).

Patterns are very general and it's common to adapt they to the specific needs we have. But, again, I'm pretty sure ORMs support that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an ORM tool like NHibernate for accessing DB? If you use something like NHibernate, you would get this behavior by means of lazy loading.

Most ORM tools do exactly what you are looking for within lazy loading - they first get the object identifiers, and upon accessing a method, they issue subsequent queries to load the related objects.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a need for a Data Transfer Object (DTO), just a "dumb" wrapper class that summarizes a business entity. I usually use something like that when I need to flatten out an object for display. Be careful, though: overuse results in an anti-pattern.

But rendering an object for display is different from limiting hits against the database.  As Randolph points out, if your intention is the latter, then use one of the existing deferred loading patterns, or better yet, use an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [registry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) pattern, you can use it to find objects and also to better manage these objects, like keeping them in a cache.